# pssh stderr askpass received prompt

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting

I'm using pssh version 2.3.1 on a RHEL 6 server so I can log into multiple clients in a single run and pull down config. While testing out I am getting an error.

```
[1] 14:45:54 [SUCCESS] user@192.168.2.25:22
Stderr: pssh-askpass received prompt: "user@192.168.2.25's     password: "
```

This is a little confusing to me as it says success while the next line looks like an error. From the man page it does say an exit status of "1" is a misc error. So no sure why it says success. Either way, my command does not seem to run as my output file is created but empty. The command I am running is:

```
pssh -i -h $HOSTFILE -v -t 25 -A -o $OUTPUTDIR $COMMAND
```

After I run this I am asked for my password, which I type in, then get the output above. I have seen a few threads that refer to a bug but that seems to only be related to older versions and RSA passphrase, not passing a plain-text password. Can anyone help figure out what might be happening?